# FedEx create shipping label not working

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, fedex

I am using magento v1.7.0.2, and also setup fedex sandbox mode. 
It is showing error while creating shipping label `" An error occurred while creating shipping label."`

When I have reviewed exception log it shows below error:

```
SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server] Schema validation failed for request. in  app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php:1475
```

We have also implement patch from [here](https://gist.github.com/philwinkle/9627533), but still it is showing same error.

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a known issue of FedEx.